# normalizing a proportion of poll results given unequal gender response rates

Tags: categorical-data, survey, proportion, normalization

I took a poll of patients who experienced at least one misdiagnosis. I'd like to analyze the data according to gender but 75% of the responses came from Females and 25% from Males.

Example: The data for the misdiagnosis category "IBS" is 4 Males and 19 Females on 19+4=23  total responses.

For Males the proportion is 4/23 = 0.17
For Females the proportion is 19/23 = 0.83

It doesn't seem reasonable to compare 0.17 to 0.83 since I the gender response of the poll was so uneven. How can I normalize the proportion so the comparison is fair?

Comment: What were the response *rates*?  That is, are you getting a disproportionate number of females because they respond to your poll at a higher rate than males, or is it because females are getting misdiagnosed more often?

Comment: I was likely unclear with the data... There were many choices of misdiagnosis of which "IBS" was just one. There were a total of 100 respondents. Of the 100, the gender breakdown was 75% F and 25% M. Not all of them were misdiagnosed with "IBS", only 23 were. For those who answered that they were misdiagnosed with "IBS" 19 were F and 4 were M.

Comment: OK, Thank you. That would seem to make *comparison* the thrust of this question rather than "normalization," which likely is an irrelevant diversion.  Could you please explain what "comparison" you wish to make? What question(s) are you asking of these data?  What are you trying to learn from them?

Comment: Ok yes, you're completely right -- comparison. So it looks to me like there's a difference between Female and Male misdiagnosis. I'd like to make a fair and quantitative comparison instead of just pontificating about the differences. I wish to compare female and male misdiagnosis for the "IBS" category. Thanks.